# Can not iterate over List with live data from Database

Tags: android, list, kotlin

I want to iterate with a for loop over my list to calculate the total amount.

I get the list from my dao with livedata, but i can't iterate over it. I get the error " For-Loop needs an iterator()"

How exacly can I solve this problem?

```
fun getTotalSum(receipts: Receipts){
    var totalCost = 0f
    val list: Flow<List<Receipts>> = receiptDao.getAllReceipts()
    for (receipts in list) {
        totalCost += receipts.total
    }
}
```

Comment: Your for loop is synchronously called with the dao method

Comment: I think this calls for a beginner's tutorial on flows, this problem really has nothing to do with Room or LiveData (by which I presume you meant Flow). Once you understand flows a bit better (or any observable data holder for that matter), it will probably become clear why there is no iterator. Not to mention that a flow might not even contain a list, so iterating over one would make little sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` in `collect` to get the totalCost

```
 list.collect {
      val totalCost = it.reduce { acc, a -> acc + a }
 }
```

Comment: Where do i put this code? Instead of the for loop?

Comment: where you are using flow to collect the data